# Custom Slider In SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, slider

I'm trying to create a horizontal slider like the one shown below in SpriteKit (in Objective C for Mac OS).

[image]

I'm certainly doing something wrong because the "knob" of the slider never moves left, it only moves right and I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm using the `mouseDragged:` method to handle everything. Here's the code below:

**Slider.m**

```
#import "Slider.h"

@interface Slider()

@property CGSize dimensions;
@property SKSpriteNode *background, *foreground, *knob;

@end

@implementation Slider

-(instancetype) initWithDimensions:(CGSize)dimensions Percentage:(double)percentage {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _dimensions = dimensions;
        _percentage = percentage;
        [self initBackgroundSprite];
        [self initForegroundSprite];
        [self initKnob];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) initBackgroundSprite {
    _background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sliderBG"];
    _background.centerRect = CGRectMake(6.0/13.0, 5.0/11.0, 1.0/13.0, 1.0/11.0);
    [_background setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0.5)];
    double xScale = _dimensions.width / _background.frame.size.width;
    double yScale = _dimensions.height / _background.frame.size.height;
    [_background setXScale:xScale];
    [_background setYScale:yScale];
    [self addChild:_background];
}

-(void) initForegroundSprite {
    _foreground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sliderFG"];
    _foreground.centerRect = CGRectMake(6.0/13.0, 5.0/11.0, 1.0/13.0, 1.0/11.0);
    [_foreground setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0.5)];
    double xScale = _dimensions.width*_percentage / _foreground.frame.size.width;
    double yScale = _dimensions.height / _foreground.frame.size.height;
    [_foreground setXScale:xScale];
    [_foreground setYScale:yScale];
    [self addChild:_foreground];
}

-(void) initKnob {
    _knob = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sliderKnob"];
    _knob.centerRect = CGRectMake(6.0/13.0, 5.0/11.0, 1.0/13.0, 1.0/11.0);
    [_knob setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0.5)];
    double scaleFactor = 2 / (_knob.frame.size.height / _background.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", _knob.frame.size.height, _background.frame.size.height);
    [_knob setScale:scaleFactor];
    [_knob setZPosition:2];
    [_knob setName:@"knob"];
    [self addChild:_knob];
}

-(void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    CGPoint location = [event locationInNode:self];
    NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:location];

    for (SKNode *node in nodes) {
        if ([node isKindOfClass:[SKSpriteNode class]]) {
            SKSpriteNode *sprite = (SKSpriteNode*)node;

            if ([sprite.name isEqualToString:@"knob"]) {
                [self updateKnobPositionWithLocation:location];
            }

        }
    }
}

-(void) updateKnobPositionWithLocation:(CGPoint)location {
    double x = location.x;
    double y = _knob.position.y; //don't want the y-pos to change

    double bgX = _background.position.x; //x pos of slider
    double width = _background.frame.size.width; //width of slider
    if (x > bgX + width)//if knob goes beyond width of slider, restrict to width
        x = bgX + width;
    else if (x < bgX)
        x = bgX;

    [_knob setPosition:CGPointMake(x, y)];
}
```

Here's a video to illustrate the behaviour:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Zfr1yQCdf-OG5kZFRWNFgxd1k

Comment: what is your x anchor point? if is 0.5 you must change to else if (x < bgX - width/2)  x = bgX- width/2;

Comment: adding to @SimonePistecchia 's comment am going to guess that _background.position.x is the center of your background,  you should be using `_background.frame.minX` and `_background.frame.maxX` instead of `position.x` and `position.x + width`.  If you made the knob a child of your background, then you would only need to worry about `[-width/2 ,
 width/2]` since the knob would be relative to its parent. (I would recommend formatting like this)  Also, I am going to predict your next problem will be moving that bar with the knob,  I would recommend looking into SKCropNode to achieve that effect.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. My anchor point is (0, 0.5) for all of my nodes so I think my calculations are fine @SimonePistecchia right? `_knob` is not a child of `_background`. I'll update the code so that you see the entire class.

Comment: can you print some position in if else?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia How would you like me to print out the positions? With a video? I used NSLog and the values of the `_knob` property were from 0 to 250, which is width of the `_background` property.

Comment: without if else, the _knob can slide back?

Comment: try to use SKConstrain

Comment: if your anchor point is 0.5.0.5. then you are saying if the position of the knob is less than the  center of the background, then the position of the knob is equal to the center of the background. This means your knob can actually go past the length of your slider by 1/2 width of the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved all of the issues with the slider class. Thanks for the help everyone. In case anyone is interested, here's the full code:

**Slider.h**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface Slider : SKSpriteNode

@property double percentage;

-(instancetype) initWithDimensions:(CGSize)dimensions Percentage:(double)percentage;

@end
```

**Slider.m**

```
#import "Slider.h"

@interface Slider()

@property CGSize dimensions;
@property SKSpriteNode *background, *foreground, *knob;
@property double backgroundWidth, foregroundWidth;
@property bool isBeingUsed;
@property SKLabelNode *percentageLabel;

@end

@implementation Slider

//creates a slider with certain dimensions and at a specific starting percentage clamped [0, 1]
-(instancetype) initWithDimensions:(CGSize)dimensions Percentage:(double)percentage {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _dimensions = dimensions;
        _percentage = percentage;
        _isBeingUsed = NO;
        [self initBackgroundSprite];
        [self initForegroundSprite];
        [self initKnob];
        [self initPercentageLabel];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

//sprite initialization
-(void) initBackgroundSprite {
    _background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sliderBG"];
    _background.centerRect = CGRectMake(6.0/13.0, 5.0/11.0, 1.0/13.0, 1.0/11.0);
    _backgroundWidth = _background.frame.size.width;
    [_background setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0.5)];
    double xScale = _dimensions.width / _backgroundWidth;
    double yScale = _dimensions.height / _background.frame.size.height;
    [_background setXScale:xScale];
    [_background setYScale:yScale];
    [self addChild:_background];
}

-(void) initForegroundSprite {
    _foreground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sliderFG"];
    _foreground.centerRect = CGRectMake(6.0/13.0, 5.0/11.0, 1.0/13.0, 1.0/11.0);
    [_foreground setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0.5)];
    _foregroundWidth = _foreground.frame.size.width;
    double xScale = _dimensions.width*_percentage / _foregroundWidth;
    double yScale = _dimensions.height / _foreground.frame.size.height;
    [_foreground setXScale:xScale];
    [_foreground setYScale:yScale];
    [self addChild:_foreground];
}

-(void) initKnob {
    _knob = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sliderKnob"];
    _knob.centerRect = CGRectMake(6.0/13.0, 5.0/11.0, 1.0/13.0, 1.0/11.0);
    [_knob setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
    double scaleFactor = 2 / (_knob.frame.size.height / _background.frame.size.height);
    [_knob setScale:scaleFactor];
    [_knob setPosition:CGPointMake(_foreground.frame.size.width, -_knob.frame.size.height*0.05)];
    [_knob setZPosition:2];
    [_knob setName:@"knob"];
    [self addChild:_knob];
}

-(void) initPercentageLabel {
    _percentageLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Hiragino Kaku Gothic Std"];
    [_percentageLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", _percentage*100]];
    [_percentageLabel setFontSize:15];
    double x = _dimensions.width * 1.05;
    double y = _knob.frame.size.height*0.05;
    [_percentageLabel setPosition:CGPointMake(x, y)];
    [_percentageLabel setHorizontalAlignmentMode:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft];
    [_percentageLabel setVerticalAlignmentMode:SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter];
    [self addChild:_percentageLabel];
}

-(void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    CGPoint location = [event locationInNode:self];
    _isBeingUsed = YES;
    [self updateKnobPositionWithLocation:location];
}

-(void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super mouseDown:event];
    CGPoint location = [event locationInNode:self];
    _isBeingUsed = YES;
    [self updateKnobPositionWithLocation:location];
}

-(void) mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super mouseUp:event];
    _isBeingUsed = NO;
}


-(void) updateKnobPositionWithLocation:(CGPoint)location {
    if (_isBeingUsed) {
        double x = location.x;
        double y = _knob.position.y; //don't want the y-pos to change

        double bgX = _background.position.x; //x pos of slider
        double width = _background.frame.size.width; //width of slider
        if (x > bgX + width)//if knob goes beyond width of slider, restrict to width
            x = bgX + width;
        else if (x < bgX)
            x = bgX;

        [_knob setPosition:CGPointMake(x, y)];
        [self updateForegroundPercentage];
        //NSLog(@"(%f, %f)", _knob.position.x, _knob.position.y);
    }
}

-(void) updateForegroundPercentage {
    _percentage = _knob.position.x / _background.frame.size.width;
    double xScale = _dimensions.width*_percentage / _foregroundWidth;
    [_foreground setXScale:xScale];

    [_percentageLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", _percentage*100]];
}

@end
```